# Accessing outputs PC axes of PCA (princomp) and using it for Random Forest and Decision Tress?

Tags: r, model, predict

How to put in my models for classification (random forest and decision trees) PCA components that I received from PCA analysis?

I have this model:

```
rf.model <- randomForest(CHURN~., data = train, importance = TRUE)
```

and I want to use first 2 components from this script:

```
pca1 <- princomp(pcaa, scores = TRUE, cor = TRUE)
```

and put it in my random forest model.

Can you please give me a hint how to do it?

Comment: Are you using PCA for RF feature selection?

Comment: Yes, I'm using PCA analysis and I have few components but I don't know how to put these components in my  RF model.